# Is it possible to render several DEMs simulatneously with QGIS2threejs?

Tags: qgis, 3d, qgis2threejs

I'd like to know if anyone knows a way of including several DEMs in one representation using QGIS2threejs. If I have two separate DEMs, each representing one modeled surface, both from the same location (so, one is above the other), how can I get a visualisation where both surfaces are included, one "floating" above the other?

Comment: Yes it is possible.  Actually it should be quite easy, just a few lines of javascript.  Look in the script for where it constructs the plane and modifies it based off the DEM.  Recreate that function, creating another plane that uses the other DEM you wish to visualize.  Then, give that plane a lower or higher "y" attribute so that it is displayed above or below the other DEM visualization in the scene.  It's hard to be specific without any code.